# TFS 2018 build definitions are not visible in vs2017 under Team Explorer panel

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am working with migration of TFS from  2013 to 2018. I just noticed that "Build" and few other tabs are missing Team Explorer panel and tried to search on internet and did not find anything helpful. If someone has any idea why build tab is missing then please guide me to bring it back. However, on web portal, I am able to see the build definition. I am using VS2017/TFS2018.

Comment: Double check VS is connected to the TFS server. (Mine often seems to lose track of the connection – but using git from the command line I often fail to notice this for a while)

Comment: VS is connected with TFS and I tried to reset the devenv as well but still build tab is missing.